# Checkbox doesn't toggle when rendered from a function

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, jsx

This is a little bizarre of a problem and I haven't been able to track down the issue. I have a checkbox / input combo I created using [Semantic-UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form) (`Form.Checkbox`). The checkbox portion is added to the input, think addon, for a little combo input situation. Desired behavior is when the checkbox is checked it allows the user to type input into the `input` portion of the combo input. The checkbox's state is managed in the component's local state.

If I just include this code:

```
<Form.Field className="field">
    <label>{field.label}</label>
    <Input
      {...field.input}
      label={{ basic: true, content: <Checkbox
        onChange={() => this.setState({sendEmail: !this.state.sendEmail})}
        checked={this.state.sendEmail} />,
      style: {'borderRight': '0px'}
      }}
      disabled={!this.state.sendEmail}
      labelPosition='left'
      placeholder='Email Address'
    />
</Form.Field>
```

in the jsx (render function) for the component, the toggling actually happens, state is managed properly etc. But when I put the same code into a function to render back the same input like so:

```
renderCheckboxInputField(field){
  return(
    <div>
      <Form.Field className="field">
        <label>{field.label}</label>
        <Input
          {...field.input}
          label={{ basic: true, content: <Checkbox
            onChange={() => this.setState({sendEmail: !this.state.sendEmail})}
            checked={this.state.sendEmail} />,
          style: {'borderRight': '0px'}
          }}
          disabled={!this.state.sendEmail}
          labelPosition='left'
          placeholder='Email Address'
        />
      </Form.Field>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and call it from here:

```
<Grid.Column>
  <Field
    name="email"
    label="Send Email"
    component={this.renderCheckboxInputField}
   />
</Grid.Column>
```

the checkbox doesn't actually visually toggle, though the state is being updated properly. You might ask why not just keep it in the first location where it already works, but a) for reusability I placed it within the function, and b) I wanted to include it this way inside of the `<Field />` component at the bottom because I am using [Redux Form](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/examples/) for validation on the input portion of the checkbox / input combo I made.

So for some clarification the `<Field />` component comes from Redux Form. The `<Form.Field />` pertains to a Semantic-UI React component. And all of the hacky stuff inside of the `<Input />` component's `label` field is me just customizing the input to look as I desire.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling this.renderCheckboxInputField without any params, but in function definition you pass 'field' and using it inside

Comment: That's a Redux Form thing. `field` refers to the `<Field />` component from which the function is being called.